# How to resize video but do not stretch/modify original video using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, size, editing

[image]Im pretty bad at video editing/property terms. Sorry in advance.

Green = Input video
Red = Output video

Sorry if this doesnt make sense. But can this be possibly achieved?

I tried searching for solutions in google, alas i need help in SO

Comment: What are the source dimensions and what do you want the playback dimensions to be? Seems like you want to correct aspect ratio in playback. This is easily done via a specific metadata setting without re-encoding anything.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you have a portrait-format vid shot with a phone, which you want to expand to landscape-format. Not without stretching the image to ridiculous proportions; the information outside the green rectangle doesn't exist. When you change the aspect ratio this way, a circle in the green rectangle will stretch to a horizontal oval shape.

Comment: scale, pad: `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "scale=1366:768:force_original_aspect_ratio=1, pad=1366:768:-1:-1, setsar=1" -crf 18 -c:a copy out.mp4`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов Why not post that as an answer?